# Match javascript objects length

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript objects:

**Input**

```
data=[];
data[0]=[{"value":29},{"value":44}]
data[1]=[{"value":16}]
data[2]=[{"value":13},{"value":11},{"value":1}]
data[3]=[{"value":13},{"value":11}]
```

The logic behind the desired output to match the length of javascript objects by adding `{value:0}` In order to achieve the desired output I have used `unshift` and `push` operations. Here is illustration of my desired output.

data1         0          0       0
0            data2       0       0
0              0       data3     0
0              0         0      data4

**Desired Output**

```
data[0]=[{"value":29},{"value":44},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}]
data[1]=[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":16},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}]
data[2]=[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":13},{"value":11},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0}]
data[3]=[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}{"value":13},{"value":11}]
```

**Current Output:**

If you look at `data[2]`, the result is unexpected. I could not able to handle this issue.

```
data[0]=[{"value":29},{"value":44},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}]
data[1]=[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":16},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}]
data[2]=[{"value":13},{"value":11},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}]
data[3]=[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}{"value":13},{"value":11}]
```

Here is **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/knu6Lhu5/9/)**

```
data=[];
data[0]=[{"value":29},{"value":44}]
data[1]=[{"value":16}]
data[2]=[{"value":13},{"value":11},{"value":1}]
data[3]=[{"value":13},{"value":11}]
debugger;
console.log(data);
alllength=0
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    m= Object.keys(data[i]).length;
    alllength=alllength+m;
}

console.log(alllength);

for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
   if(i==0)
   {
       m=Object.keys(data[i]).length;
       for(j=0;j<alllength-m;j++)
       {
           data[i].splice(m+j+1, 0, {"value":0});
       }
   }

   else if(i==data.length-1)
   {
       n=Object.keys(data[i]).length;
       for(j=0;j<alllength-n;j++)
       {
           data[i].unshift({"value":0});
       }

   }

   else
   {
     self.n="";
     k=Object.keys(data[i-1]).length;
     for (n=0;n<k;n++)
     {
         if(data[i-1][n].value==0)
         {
             console.log(n);
             for(j=0;j<n;j++)
             {
                data[i].unshift({"value":0});
             }

              m=Object.keys(data[i]).length;
              for(j=0;j<alllength-m;j++)
              {
                 data[i].splice(m+j+1, 0, {"value":0});
              }
             break;
        }
    }
  }
}
console.log(data)
```

Comment: what's your existing code?

Comment: I have added the code here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `reduce` and `map` which might need to be handled with an external libary.

```js
var data=[];
data[0]=[{"value":29},{"value":44}]
data[1]=[{"value":16}]
data[2]=[{"value":13},{"value":11},{"value":1}]
data[3]=[{"value":13},{"value":11}]

var totalLength = data.reduce(function(length, item) { 
 return length + item.length; 
}, 0);
    
var key = 0; 
data = data.map(function(item) { 
var out = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) { 
    out.push({value: 0}); 
} 
out.splice.apply(out, [key, item.length].concat(item)); 
key += item.length;  
return out; 
});

console.log(data);
```

This could be further optimized with some of the approaches already shown.

Comment: t is super code, I have marked as an answer. I would like to know how I could able to add another objects. For example, `data[0]= [{"value":29,"category": "cat1"},{"value":44, "category": "cat1"},{"value":0,"category": "cat1"}, ........]`,  for `data[1] `--> `category: "cat2", etc..`

Comment: Adding more data to the objects should be fine, but if you mean add them as part of this mapping then I would track the index `data.map(function(item, index) { /*...*/ })` and then add that to the item `item.cat = index`; before it gets pushed to the `out` array.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, A few things here.

1) You are going to increase the time complexity of your algorithm by calling Object.keys on an array. Data[i] is an array of objects, so calling data[i].length will work just fine instead of Object.keys(data[i]).length. Arrays keep track of the length separately, where calling Object.keys is going to do several operations under the hood which is going to slow down your algorithm

2) Your problem lies here: On line 43, you set n to zero

```
for (n=0;n<k;n++)
```

Then, you check to see if the value of the objects in the previous array are equal to zero

```
if(data[i-1][n].value==0)
```

when n === 0, this is going to be true, because the first several objects in the previous array have values that equate to 0.

Next, you go through and add the necessary 0 value objects to create the structure that you want with this code

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
         {
            data[i].unshift({"value":0});
         }
```

afterwards, you add the non-zero values and break the loop
The problem is, when n === 0 and you make the previous for loop `for(j=0;j<n;j++)`, basically you are saying `for(j=0, j< 0; j++)` which skips the for loop

The if statement gets executed, the zero value block gets skipped and it goes straight to adding values

Answer (score 2):

```
data=[];
data[0]=[{"value":29},{"value":44}]
data[1]=[{"value":16}]
data[2]=[{"value":13},{"value":11},{"value":1}]
data[3]=[{"value":13},{"value":11}]
debugger;
console.log(data);
alllength=0
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    m= Object.keys(data[i]).length;
    alllength=alllength+m;
}

offset= 0;
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    m=Object.keys(data[i]).length;

    for (j=0;j<offset;j++) {
       data[i].unshift({"value":0});
    }
    offset+= m;

    while (Object.keys(data[i]).length < alllength) {
       data[i].push({"value":0});
    }  
 }
```